# Assumptions of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous real-valued random variable indicating the fragility of a firm. Suppose that the firm defaults if $X$ takes a value above a threshold $u>0$. Hence $$
Prob(X>u) 
$$
is the probability of default.

A very basic intuition could be that the higher is the value taken by $X$, the higher should be the probability of default. Does this statement make sense? And, if it makes sense, which assumptions on the dstribution of $X$ can represent it?

Comment: But as you said, if X exceeds u then there is default for sure. So, what do you mean when you say that the higher the value the higher the probability of default. Do not get confused. There is only acertainty on the value of X (and therefore probability makes sense for X) But once you know X there is no probability of default. The firm either defaults (if X was greater than u) or not (if otherwise).

Comment: Perhaps $u$ should be an index of *resiliency*, then you can say that the higher $u$ is, the more robust the firm is. $X$ makes more sense as the actual event that may cause failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a statement like this: The higher the probability of high values of $X$, the more likely it is that the firm defaults. That is, you are comparing probability distributions of $X$.

Mathematically, you could use the notion of [first order stochastic dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order_stochastic_dominance) (FOSD). Suppose you have two different distributions for $X$. Denote the cumulative distribution functions by $F(z)=Pr(X_F\le z)$ and $G(z)=Pr(X_G\le z)$, respectively.

$F$ first order stochastically dominates $G$ if $F(z)\le G(z)~\forall z\in\mathcal{X}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the set of possible $X$, and $F(z)< G(z)$ for at least one  $z\in\mathcal{X}$. Hence, if $X$ is distributed according to $F$, it tends to have higher values, and indeed has a higher expected value. In your problem, it means that default is more likely if $X$ is drawn from distribution $F$ than when it is drawn from $G$.

So one assumption on the distribution of $X$ where your intuition makes sense would be: "If higher values of $X$ are more likely in a FOSD sense, then probability of default is higher". But as the first comment says: as soon as you know the realization of $X$, there is no uncertainty any more.

In terms of economics, another approach you could take is to assume that the firm specific parameter $u_i$ is unknown, but the distribution of $u_i$ is known. Then for a higher $X$ the probability of default would be higher, because it is less likely that $u_i$ is above $X$ to prevent default.